# db2, fetch first 20 records if timestamp is older than 7 years

Tags: java, sql, database, db2

I'm working on a data purging app and using db2 database and wish to have have a select query which means this:

```
"SELECT PAYMENT.PAYMENTID FROM PAYMENT
 fetch first 20 rows only 
 WHERE PAYMENT.PAYMENTDATE > '7 years'"
```

`PAYMENTDATE` column is *timestamp*. how can i say greater than *7 years* for that select using *java*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "using java", but the WHERE clause should probably look something like `...WHERE PAYMENT.PAYMENTDATE < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 7 YEARS`. "Older" means the timestamp value is actually smaller than the one you're comparing it with, right?

Also, your FETCH FIRST clause is misplaced; it should come at the very end of the statement.

Comment: Agreed about the 'using Java' bit - unless you're explicitly needing to do something in your application layer, I'd be doing this as a DB scheduled job.  Especially as pulling in the rows using a cursor will give **terrible** performance.

Comment: There is no ORDER BY clause, so there is no guarantee how DB2 will choose which 20 rows are the "first" 20.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse how can you predict performance on a database for which you have NO statistics?  There might be 500 million rows, or only 5000 rows. There might be an index by payment date.  There might be an index which only includes old records. We don't know the distribution curve of these dates.  It could be on a set of relatively new accounts, with increasing number of accounts being affect each month, thus having mostly newer transactions.  Or it could be older accounts being paid off and closing with no new accounts being added, thus the distribution could be skewed towards older dates.

Comment: If you have an index by payment date, and ORDER BY payment date, this type of query should finish as quickly as you can blink. Faster if you are on a mainframe or large Power System.

Comment: so this statement should work?....

selectPaymentIDBy7Years = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT PAYMENT.PAYMENTID FROM PAYMENT "
                + "WHERE PAYMENT.PAYMENTDATE < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 7 YEARS fetch first 20 rows only");